# Gatsby.js is not generating the dynamic pages that the gatsby-node.js file's graphql query is properly instructing it to generate

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have run `gatsby clean` before `npm run develop` but still it has not made a difference...

My gatsby-node.js file has been looked at by others who are familiar with the Gatsby framework, and they're not sure what the problem is either...

Here is my gatsby-node.js file:

```
/**
 * Implement Gatsby's Node APIs in this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/
 */

// You can delete this file if you're not using it
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(
    `
      {
        products: allStrapiProduct {
          edges {
            node {
              name
              strapiId
              description
              category {
                name
              }
              variants {
                id
                color
                size
                style
                price
                images {
                  localFile {
                    childImageSharp {
                      gatsbyImageData
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        categories: allStrapiCategory {
          edges {
            node {
              strapiId
              name
              description
              filterOptions {
                Size {
                  checked
                  label
                }
                Style {
                  checked
                  label
                }
                Color {
                  checked
                  label
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  if (result.errors) {
    throw result.errors
  }

  const products = result.data.products.edges
  const categories = result.data.categories.edges

  products.forEach(product => {
    createPage({
      path: `/${product.node.category.name.toLowerCase()}/${
        product.node.name.split(' ')[0]
      }`,
      component: require.resolve('./src/templates/ProductDetail.js'),
      context: {
        name: product.node.name,
        id: product.node.strapiId,
        category: product.node.category.name,
        description: product.node.description,
        variants: product.node.variants,
        product,
      },
    })
  })

  categories.forEach(category => {
    createPage({
      path: `/${category.node.name.toLowerCase()}`,
      component: require.resolve('./src/templates/ProductList.js'),
      context: {
        name: category.node.name,
        description: category.node.description,
        id: category.node.strapiId,
        filterOptions: category.node.filterOptions,
      },
    })
  })
}

exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [{ test: /react-spring-3d-carousel/, use: loaders.null() }],
      },
    }, 
        )
  }
}

exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /bad-module/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Here is my gatsby-config.js file:

```
require("dotenv").config()

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `VAR-X`,
    description: `The premier developer clothing line. By developers, for developers. High quality, custom-designed shirts, hats, and hoodies.`,
    author: `Zachary Reece`,
    keywords: [
      "clothing",
      "developer",
      "programmer",
      "coding",
      "code",
      "websites",
      "web developer",
      "hats",
      "shirts",
      "hoodies",
    ],
    siteUrl: "https://formstorm.design",
    twitterUsername: "@zacharydreece",
    defaultImage: "",
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-material-ui`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-robots-txt`,
      options: {
        host: "https://formstorm.design",
        sitemap: "https://formstorm.design/sitemap.xml",
        policy: [{ userAgent: "*", allow: "/" }],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-loadable-components-ssr`,
      options: {
        // Whether replaceHydrateFunction should call ReactDOM.hydrate or ReactDOM.render
        // Defaults to ReactDOM.render on develop and ReactDOM.hydrate on build
        useHydrate: true,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader",
      options: {
        google: {
          families: [
            "Philosopher:700:latin",
            "Montserrat:700,600,500,400,300:latin",
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
      options: {
        apiURL: process.env.GATSBY_STRAPI_URL,
        queryLimit: 1000, // Default to 100
        collectionTypes: [`product`, `category`, `variant`],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
      options: {
        defaults: {
          formats: [`auto`, `webp`],
          placeholder: "blurred",
          breakpoints: [300, 600, 960, 1280, 1920],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `VAR-X`,
        short_name: `VAR-X`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#99B898`,
        theme_color: `#99B898`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/favicon.png`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

Here is my gatsby-browser.js file:

```
/**
 * Implement Gatsby's Browser APIs in this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/
 */

// You can delete this file if you're not using it
import RootWrapper from "./src/components/ui/root-wrapper"
export const wrapRootElement = RootWrapper
```

Here is the root-wrapper.js file utilizing the RootWrapper from my gatsby-browser.js and gatsby-ssr.js file:

```
import React from "react"
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import { ApolloWrapper } from "../../apollo/ApolloWrapper"
import { UserWrapper, FeedbackWrapper, CartWrapper } from "../../contexts"
import theme from "./theme"

export default ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <ApolloWrapper>
        <UserWrapper>
          <FeedbackWrapper>
            <CartWrapper>{element}</CartWrapper>
          </FeedbackWrapper>
        </UserWrapper>
      </ApolloWrapper>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Here is my gatsby-ssr.js file:

```
/**
 * Implement Gatsby's SSR (Server Side Rendering) APIs in this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/
 */

// You can delete this file if you're not using it
import RootWrapper from './src/components/ui/root-wrapper'


export const wrapRootElement =
  typeof window !== 'undefined' && window ? RootWrapper : null
```

Lastly, here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "JAMstack-Course",
  "private": true,
  "description": "The frontend of a JAMstack e-commerce platform built for a Udemy course.",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Zachary Reece <jamstack.course@gmail.com>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.2.9",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.15.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.21",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.2.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.12.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.0.6",
    "gatsby": "^3.14.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^1.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-loadable-components-ssr": "^3.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^3.14.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-material-ui": "^2.1.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.2.28",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.11",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.6.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^3.14.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^4.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader": "^1.0.4",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.30",
    "gatsby-source-strapi": "^1.0.2",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^3.14.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-resize-aware": "^3.1.1",
    "react-spring": "^9.2.4",
    "react-spring-3d-carousel": "^1.2.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@types/node": "^16.10.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.32.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.32.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-wesbos": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/zreecespieces/jamstack-course"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/zreecespieces/jamstack-course/issues"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running gatsby clean first, and then try it again…

Comment: i already tried that!

Answer (score 0):

you realise your second `exports.onCreateWebpackConfig` is overriding the first one, right?